# sum by group, but exclude values below designated id

Tags: r

I'm trying to go from this:

```
#Starting df
name = c("tom", "tom", "tom", "chris", "chris", "chris", "jen", "jen", "jen") 
value = c(2,10,"end",45,"end",13,6,"end",13) 
df = data.frame(name,value)
```

or this (which uses NA as the cutoff)

```
#Starting df
name = c("tom", "tom", "tom", "chris", "chris", "chris", "jen", "jen", "jen") 
value = c(2,10,NA,45,NA,13,6,NA,13) 
starting_df = data.frame(name,value)
```

To this:

```
#Ending df
name = c("tom", "tom", "tom", "chris", "chris", "chris", "jen", "jen", "jen") 
value = c(12,12,12,45,45,45,6,6,6) 
ending_df = data.frame(name,value)
```

The idea here is to sum by group(name in this case), which I can easily do using `group_by` function from `dplyr`, but I  need to remove all values beneath `NAs` or text that states `end`.  The values beneath these cutoffs cannot be included in my sum.  I've been working on this all night and am out of ideas.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Should the sum for `chris` not be 58 and for `jen` 19 ?

Comment: try: group_by(name) %>% mutate(value = sum(value, na.rm = T))

Comment: no, I can't use values beneath `NA` or `end` for my sum calculations.  they turn out to be dups in this particular data set I'm working with.

Comment: @neilfws I don't think so. `chris` stays at 45 because 13 is below an `NA` and we only want to sum until the cutoff (i.e. until the `NA` for each group).

Comment: oh, so you literally want to exclude vals whose rows come after NAs?

Comment: OK, now I understand what is meant by "beneath NAs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'name', convert the 'value' to `numeric` (in case if the column is `character`, if it is `factor`, use `as.numeric(as.character(value))`) so that the non-numeric elements get converted to `NA`, then get the index of the first NA element with `which` and `is.na`, and find the `sum` of 'value' until that row

```
starting_df %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate(value = as.numeric(value), 
           value = sum(value[seq_len(which(is.na(value))[1])], na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   name [3]
#    name value
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1    tom    12
#2    tom    12
#3    tom    12
#4  chris    45
#5  chris    45
#6  chris    45
#7    jen     6
#8    jen     6
#9    jen     6
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option would be using `ave` where for each group (`name`) we find the index where the first `NA` occurs using `which.max` and sum `values` until that index.

```
starting_df$value <- ave(starting_df$value, starting_df$name, FUN = function(x) 
                                sum(x[1:which.max(is.na(x)) - 1]))

starting_df

#   name value
#1   tom    12
#2   tom    12
#3   tom    12
#4 chris    45
#5 chris    45
#6 chris    45
#7   jen     6
#8   jen     6
#9   jen     6
```

---

As @thelatemail commented, we can also do this using `cumsum`. We select the maximum value of `cumsum` from each group ignoring the `NA`s.

```
starting_df$value <- ave(starting_df$value, starting_df$name, FUN = function(x) 
                              max(cumsum(x), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: nice use of which.max...never seen that before

Comment: Variation, since cumsum is `NA` after the first `NA` is hit. `with(starting_df, ave(value, name, FUN=function(x) max(cumsum(x),na.rm=TRUE) ) )`

Comment: @thelatemail This is nice use of `cumsum` .