# conditional deletion of rows, based on group and specified text

Tags: r, dataframe

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47194247/sum-by-group-but-exclude-values-below-designated-id) earlier regarding summing values by group, excluding values below NA or text.  This question is similar, but instead of summing by group, I'd like to remove all values below specific text (`end` in this case) grouped by id(`name` in this case).  For example,

I'd like to go from here:

```
#Starting df
name = c("tom", "tom", "tom", "chris", "chris", "chris","chris", "jen", "jen", "jen","jen","jen") 
value = c(2,10,"end",45,"end",13,20,6,"end",13,3,5) 
start_df = data.frame(name,value)
```

to here:

```
#Ending df
name = c("tom", "tom", "tom", "chris", "chris","jen", "jen") 
value = c(2,10,"end",45,"end",6,"end") 
end_df = data.frame(name,value)
```

There is other text in addition to `end` so I was hoping to find a solution that allows me to specify the text.  Any ideas on how I could do this?  Thank you R community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `start_df2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

start_df2 <- start_df %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(flag = ifelse(value %in% "end", 1, NA)) %>%
  fill(flag, .direction = "up") %>%
  filter(!is.na(flag)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  select(-ID, -flag)

start_df2

# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#     name  value
#    <fctr> <fctr>
# 1    tom      2
# 2    tom     10
# 3    tom    end
# 4  chris     45
# 5  chris    end
# 6    jen      6
# 7    jen    end
```

Comment: it didn't come out that way for me, unsure why it's showing like that in the output.

Comment: @CurtF. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I have updated my post.

Comment: @CurtF. Thanks. I got another update. Hopefully, it is the last one. Somehow after the `filter` function the row order changes. So I added an `ID` column and `arrange` based on `ID` after the `fill` and `filter`. Now the code generates the exact same output as `end_df`.

Answer (score 4):

Another `dplyr` based solution:

```
start_df %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate(rownum = row_number(), keeprows = (value=='end') * rownum) %>%
    filter(rownum <= max(keeprows)) %>%
    select(-keeprows)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `slice` to get it, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

start_df %>% 
 group_by(name) %>% 
 slice(1L:which(value == 'end'))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 2
> # Groups:   name [3]
>     name  value
>   <fctr> <fctr>
> 1  chris     45
> 2  chris    end
> 3    jen      6
> 4    jen    end
> 5    tom      2
> 6    tom     10
> 7    tom    end
> ```